# boost multi_index - how to iterate through it if element type supports move-semantic only?

Tags: c++, boost

```
typedef boost::multi_index_container<foo, ...

struct foo {
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar; // requires move-semantic only
    foo() { bar = std::make_unique<Bar>(); }
    foo(foo&&) = default;
};
```

I haven't any problems with `push_back` - just using `push_back(std::move(...))`.

Also, no problems with:

```
auto it = container.get<...>().find(...);
container.erase(it);
```

But I also need iterate all elements of container. I doing:

```
for (auto it = container.begin(); auto it = container.end(); ++it) {
   some_foo(*it); // For instance, another_container_of_same_type.push_back(*it) - to merge 2 containers
}
```

Or, in special case:

```
for (auto it = container.begin(); auto it = container.end(); ++it) {
   // some logics
   another_container_of_same_type.push_back(*it); //another container defined same as first one
   // some logics
}
```

And it not compiles!

I tried:

```
some_foo(std::move(*it))
some_foo(std::move(it))
some_foo(it)
some_foo(*it)
```

Not compiles. It wants copying constructor nor moving...

**Warning: NO, it is not simply merging two containers, I using my custom logics in the merging, also using iterating not for merging only.**

Comment: Why don't you include a self-contained piece of code?

Comment: @sehe What should I include? You want see my indexes of container? Do they matter for the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the declaration for `some_foo`, but likely you didn't take the parameter by reference.

Here's a simple, self-contained example that should get you going.

**<kbd>[Live On COliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f1c5b3006330c7b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>

// move-only
struct foo {
    foo()           = default;
    foo(foo&&)      = default;
    foo(foo const&) = delete;
    foo& operator=(foo&&)      = default;
    foo& operator=(foo const&) = delete;
};

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

using foos = bmi::multi_index_container<foo, bmi::indexed_by<bmi::sequenced<> > >;

void some_foo(foo const&) {}

int main() {
    foos c;

    for (auto& el : c) {
        some_foo(el);
    }
}
```

Compiles fine.

Comment: Note: I included a self-contained example, if you get stuck again later, modify it to post a better question.

Comment: I calling another_container.push_back() as the some_foo.  (And I mentioned such case in the question) The another_container is defined 100% same as first one.

Comment: Now that it has become completely obvious that wish to move the element - always, I'm marking this as duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082394/move-element-from-boost-multi-index-array - here is no "another_container.push_back()" which is one of my cases here! Your solution isn't applicable for that case because I couldn't rewrite "push_back".

Comment: Ok, I asked another question about special push_back case, rathen than "moving" at whole: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547949/boost-multi-index-how-to-add-an-element-from-one-container-to-another-if-its-t