# Is there any way to move an element from ordered_index ed multi_index?

Tags: c++, boost, extract, multi-index

Since C++17, `std::set` has `extract()` member function that support moving the node from the container. Here is an example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <set>

struct trace {
    trace() {
        std::cout << this << ":" << " construct" << std::endl;
    }
    ~trace() {
        std::cout << this << ":" << " destruct" << std::endl;
    }
    trace(trace& other) {
        std::cout << this << ":" << " copy construct from " << &other << std::endl;
    }
    trace(trace&& other) {
        std::cout << this << ":" << " move construct from " << &other << std::endl;
    }
    trace& operator=(trace const& other) {
        std::cout << this << ":" << " copy assign from    " << &other << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    trace& operator=(trace&& other) {
        std::cout << this << ":" << " move assign from    " << &other << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

inline bool operator<(trace const& lhs, trace const& rhs) {
    std::cout << &lhs << " < " << &rhs << std::endl;
    return &lhs < &rhs;
}

int main () {
    std::set<trace> s;
    s.insert(trace());
    s.insert(trace());
    s.insert(trace());
    auto it = s.begin();
    ++it;

    assert(s.size() == 3);
    std::cout << "[[extract]]" << std::endl;
    trace t = std::move(s.extract(it).value());
    assert(s.size() == 2);
}
```

Running demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZZHkZV1DUZpM3YrU

I got the following result:

```
0x7ffd30bbfbd0: construct
0x55edd361d2a0: move construct from 0x7ffd30bbfbd0
0x7ffd30bbfbd0: destruct
0x7ffd30bbfbc8: construct
0x7ffd30bbfbc8 < 0x55edd361d2a0
0x55edd361d2a0 < 0x7ffd30bbfbc8
0x7ffd30bbfbc8 < 0x55edd361d2a0
0x55edd361d2d0: move construct from 0x7ffd30bbfbc8
0x7ffd30bbfbc8: destruct
0x7ffd30bbfbc0: construct
0x7ffd30bbfbc0 < 0x55edd361d2a0
0x7ffd30bbfbc0 < 0x55edd361d2d0
0x55edd361d2d0 < 0x7ffd30bbfbc0
0x7ffd30bbfbc0 < 0x55edd361d2d0
0x55edd361d300: move construct from 0x7ffd30bbfbc0
0x7ffd30bbfbc0: destruct
[[extract]]
0x7ffd30bbfbb0: move construct from 0x55edd361d2d0
0x55edd361d2d0: destruct
0x7ffd30bbfbb0: destruct
0x55edd361d300: destruct
0x55edd361d2a0: destruct
```

After `[[extract]]`, the container doesn't access to the move from object. It is fine.

I'm looking for a way to do the same thing on `boost::multi_index`.

I tried the same way as the following Q&A:
[Move element from boost multi_index array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082394/move-element-from-boost-multi-index-array)

I tried the same approach:

```
namespace mi = boost::multi_index;

using mi_trace = mi::multi_index_container<
    trace,
    mi::indexed_by<
        mi::ordered_unique<
            mi::identity<trace>
        >
    >
>;

int main () {
    mi_trace mi;

    mi.insert(trace());
    mi.insert(trace());
    mi.insert(trace());

    auto it = mi.begin();
    ++it;

    assert(mi.size() == 3);
    std::optional<trace> target;
    std::cout << "[[modify]]" << std::endl;
    if (mi.modify(
            it,
            [&](auto& e) {
                target.emplace(std::move(e));
            }
        )
    ) {
        std::cout << "[[erase]]" << std::endl;
        mi.erase(it);
        assert(mi.size() == 2);
    }
}
```

Running demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/eKpGDpMBbx5aRz9O

And got the following output:

```
[[modify]]
0x7fffe1f77c66: move construct from 0x55fdda3272e0
0x55fdda3272b0 < 0x55fdda3272e0
0x55fdda3272e0 < 0x55fdda327310
[[erase]]
0x55fdda3272e0: destruct
0x7fffe1f77c66: destruct
0x55fdda3272b0: destruct
0x55fdda327310: destruct
```

`multi_index` container accesses moved from object (`0x55fdda3272e0`) after modify lambda returned. I think that it is for reordering. `modify()` doesn't know that I use `modify()` with `erase()`. For `random_access_index`, it works well because the container doesn't need to reorder but it doesn't work for `ordered_index`.

Is there any way to move an element from `ordered_index`ed `multi_index` ?

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand your question. Let's take the first part - output looks fine to me. What output do you expect?

Comment: The first part output is fine. The last output is bad, because 0x55fdda3272e0 is accessed after moved.

Comment: I want to do the same thing as `std::set::extract` using `boost::muti_index` ordered index.

Comment: I'm still not sure what do you try to achieve. You have iterator `it` that point to the element you need, if you what to move from it - just move and erase it from the container. What is wrong with this?

Comment: Do you mean this https://wandbox.org/permlink/WSHwdvNvFtp5CMPJ ? `multi_index` returns `const_iterator` so I can't move from the iterator.

Comment: See https://wandbox.org/permlink/pxEdj9Dq1fOoU6Uk . The type of `*it` is `trace const&`. So `std::move(*it)` is fallbacked to copy.

Comment: Oh, right... Well, in your second part you do pretty much the right thing, but when you move out data it reorders container ('cos you moved out only data, elements still there) I can see any way to pop this element out the same way `extract()` does.

Comment: I start thinking that we can implement `extract()` for `multi_index`, but it doesn't exist so far. `std::set::extract()` returns `node_type`(node-handle?). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle. I'm not sure the internal node structure of `multi_index`. I think that I should create the issue as the feature request for `extract()` on https://github.com/boostorg/multi_index.

Comment: Yes, it does make sense.

Comment: I created an issue. https://github.com/boostorg/multi_index/issues/27

Comment: Note that the reason why boost::multi_index has iterators that point to constant reference is in large part motivated by the container invariants that boost::multi_index provides.

If you have a multi-index container, and you 'move from' one of the items in the container, the resulting `valid-but-unspecified` object that you moved from will not necessarily hold the invariants of the container.

Boost::multi_index provides a modify_index function which allows the user to modify the data held by the container, and if the invariants are violated, a roll-back function is executed to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to extract a value from a `multi_index_container` while making sure the element is erased right after value extraction:

```
struct extract_value_exception{};

template<typename MultiIndexContainerIndex>
auto extract_value(
    MultiIndexContainerIndex& i,
    typename MultiIndexContainerIndex::iterator it)
{
    using value_type = typename MultiIndexContainerIndex::value_type;

    std::optional<value_type> o;
    try{
        i.modify(it, [&](value_type& x){
            o.emplace(std::move(x));
            throw extract_value_exception{};
        });
    }
    catch(const extract_value_exception&){}
    return std::move(*o);
}
```

Complete example follows.

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nCscbd6KGiT6tp9Y)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

struct trace {
    trace() {
        std::cout << this << ":" << " construct" << std::endl;
    }
    ~trace() {
        std::cout << this << ":" << " destruct" << std::endl;
    }
    trace(trace& other) {
        std::cout << this << ":" << " copy construct from " << &other << std::endl;
    }
    trace(trace&& other) {
        std::cout << this << ":" << " move construct from " << &other << std::endl;
    }
    trace& operator=(trace const& other) {
        std::cout << this << ":" << " copy assign from    " << &other << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    trace& operator=(trace&& other) {
        std::cout << this << ":" << " move assign from    " << &other << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

inline bool operator<(trace const& lhs, trace const& rhs) {
    std::cout << &lhs << " < " << &rhs << std::endl;
    return &lhs < &rhs;
}

struct extract_value_exception{};

template<typename MultiIndexContainerIndex>
auto extract_value(
    MultiIndexContainerIndex& i,
    typename MultiIndexContainerIndex::iterator it)
{
    using value_type = typename MultiIndexContainerIndex::value_type;

    std::optional<value_type> o;
    try{
        i.modify(it, [&](value_type& x){
            o.emplace(std::move(x));
            throw extract_value_exception{};
        });
    }
    catch(const extract_value_exception&){}
    return std::move(*o);
}

int main () {
    boost::multi_index_container<trace> s;
    s.insert(trace());
    s.insert(trace());
    s.insert(trace());
    auto it = s.begin();
    ++it;

    assert(s.size() == 3);
    std::cout << "[[extract]]" << std::endl;
    trace t = extract_value(s, it);
    assert(s.size() == 2);
}
```

**Output**

```
0x7ffd5feed89d: construct
0x21f7190: move construct from 0x7ffd5feed89d
0x7ffd5feed89d: destruct
0x7ffd5feed89e: construct
0x7ffd5feed89e < 0x21f7190
0x21f7190 < 0x7ffd5feed89e
0x21f71c0: move construct from 0x7ffd5feed89e
0x7ffd5feed89e: destruct
0x7ffd5feed89f: construct
0x7ffd5feed89f < 0x21f7190
0x7ffd5feed89f < 0x21f71c0
0x21f71c0 < 0x7ffd5feed89f
0x21f71f0: move construct from 0x7ffd5feed89f
0x7ffd5feed89f: destruct
[[extract]]
0x7ffd5feed836: move construct from 0x21f71c0
0x21f71c0: destruct
0x7ffd5feed867: move construct from 0x7ffd5feed836
0x7ffd5feed836: destruct
0x7ffd5feed867: destruct
0x21f7190: destruct
0x21f71f0: destruct
```

Comment: Thank you! It perfectly works. If someone worries about performance, see https://github.com/boostorg/multi_index/issues/27. We could have `extract()` for `multi_index` in the future.

Comment: Since `throw extract_value_exception{};` is needed, it'd be good to get an explanation for _why_ it's needed. Using exceptions for  normal flowcontrol is rather unusual.

Comment: @Joaquín M López Muñoz is the "throw" necessary to prevent the container to re-sort the empty element?

Comment: The `throw` bit is necessary so that `modify` erases the (by now moved from) element. `modify` must erase the element if something goes wrong (cause it can't guarantee it's properly positioned), and we're taking advantage ot this behavior for the `extract_value` hack.