# Does boost.multiindex provide "erase and return erased value" mechanism?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

Basically I'm looking for the functionality akin to `std::map::extract`.

TL;DR

I currently have a multi-index container with two views: insert order and sorted by an "id" member function of the contained element. The multi-index container currently operates on elements of a pointer type. However, the container fully owns the objects it contains and I'd like to change the contained elements to be unique_ptr instead.

However, it looks non-trivial to do "remove a given element preserving its value" step with unique_ptr.

Since the pointer is to an abstract base class, I can't use swap() because this would require me to construct an "empty" object of an abstract type.

Edit:
Thanks to the fact that compiler explorer supports linking to 3rd party libraries, I was able to create what I think is the minimal reproducible [example](https://godbolt.org/z/edE4cMd8a)

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/indexed_by.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/tag.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>



class Base {
  public:
    virtual size_t GetId() const = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    size_t GetId() const { return 42; }
};


int main(int, char**) {
    // A tag to view elements in the order of insertion.
    struct Sequenced{};
    // A tag to view elements in the order sorted by type id.
    struct Ordered{};

    using ContainerType = boost::multi_index_container<
        // Elements are pointers to Base.
        std::unique_ptr<Base>,

        boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
            boost::multi_index::sequenced<boost::multi_index::tag<Sequenced>>,
            boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<
              boost::multi_index::tag<Ordered>,
              boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<Base, size_t,
                                                &Base::GetId>>>>;

    ContainerType container;

    // Insert an element.
    auto& ordered_view = container.get<Ordered>();
    auto new_element = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    auto insert_result = ordered_view.insert(std::move(new_element));
    if (!insert_result.second) return -1;

   // Now I just need to extract the element with GetId == 42
   // This works only starting with boost v1.74
   std::unique_ptr<Base> extracted = std::move(ordered_view.extract(42).value());
}
```

Starting with boost v1.74, hashed views support "extract" member function. I don't think it's possible to do what I want to do prior to that version. The swap trick mentioned in the comments won't work as it does not exist for hashed views. And furthermore, for the views it does exist (sequenced) it actually swaps the whole container, not individual elements.

Comment: You can swap two `std::unique_ptr<abstract_base_class>` fine, no problem. Please show your code in a [mre].

Comment: Yes, you can swap with an already existing unique_ptr<base>. But if all you want is to extract a ptr from the container, then you'd be forced to create a unique_ptr<base> from scratch, which requires creating a concrete object of Derived::Base. I could probably define a dummy "Derived" just for this purpose, but that's ugly. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Why would you need to create a `unique_ptr<base>` from scratch? You already have a pointer to the object. It's no different than having a raw pointer except that you can't accidentally _copy_  a `unique_ptr` and then have _two_ owners. Please show your code so that we can clearly see the setup and the issues you are struggling with.

Comment: swap function expect an object to swap with an object in the container, correct?
Here's an example of that using vector: https://godbolt.org/z/n34Pz5q19

Comment: This is why you should show a [mre]. Of course you can't create an instance of `Base` as you try in `std::make_unique<Base>();`. If you want to swap with an empty `unique_Ptr<Base>`, just default-initialize `extracted` [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/dsWEGs6jc) _or_ move the element out [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/nPznP6rjc). Sidenote: You've forgotten `virtual ~Base() = default;` in `Base`

Comment: Point take about showing reproducible examples in the original note. And thank you for reminding me that default-constructed unique_ptr *is* the thing :) That approach should work. Your second example won't work though as elements of the multi-index container are const. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm working with the code you've shown so don't expect it to work with other containers. If you want the best help possible, include a short example in the question that actually uses the same classes as you use.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Thanks to the fact that compiler explorer supports linking to 3rd party libraries, I was able to create what I think is the minimal reproducible example: https://godbolt.org/z/edE4cMd8a

Starting with boost v1.74, hashed views support "extract" member function.
I don't think it's possible to do what I want to do prior to that version. The swap won't work as it does not exist for hashed views.

Comment: Great, but please update you question and put the code in there and I'll take a look tomorrow. Bedtime here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest upgrading. If that's not an option, I can only see a helper implementation that works if

- you have a temporary key value that you know is not in the container
- or you can use a key extractor that doesn't require the `unique_ptr` to be non-null

I'll demonstrate the first option using a chosen INVKEY of `-1` (0xFFFFFFFF) to act as the temporary "deletion" key:

```
template <typename Idx, typename V = Idx::value_type> V extract(Idx& idx, size_t key) {
    auto it = idx.find(key);
    if (it == idx.end())
        return nullptr;

    BasePtr tmp = std::make_unique<Derived>(Base::INVKEY);
    idx.modify(it, [&tmp](BasePtr& element) { //
        element.swap(tmp);
    });
    idx.erase(it);
    return tmp;
}
```

> *Note that it gracefully returns `nullptr` when the key wasn't found. This may or may not be what you want*

### Demo Program

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d9629bf1462c1ec)**

```
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/indexed_by.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/tag.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

struct Base {
    static constexpr size_t INVKEY = -1ul;

    virtual size_t GetId() const = 0;
    virtual ~Base()              = default;
};

using BasePtr = std::unique_ptr<Base>;

struct Derived : Base {
    Derived(size_t id) : id_(id) {}
    size_t GetId() const override { return id_; }

  private:
    size_t id_;
};

template <> struct fmt::formatter<Base, char> : fmt::formatter<size_t> {
    auto format(Base const& b, auto& ctx) const { return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", b.GetId()); }
};

template <typename T> struct fmt::formatter<std::unique_ptr<T>, char> : fmt::formatter<std::decay_t<T>> {
    auto format(std::unique_ptr<T> const& p, auto& ctx) const {
        if (p)
            return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", *p);
        else
            return fmt::format_to(ctx.out(), "(nullptr)");
    }
};

using ContainerType = boost::multi_index_container<
    BasePtr,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::sequenced<boost::multi_index::tag<struct Sequenced>>,
        boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<struct Ordered>,
                                          boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<Base, size_t, &Base::GetId>> //
        >>;

template <typename Idx, typename V = Idx::value_type> V extract(Idx& idx, size_t key) {
    auto it = idx.find(key);
    if (it == idx.end())
        return nullptr;

    BasePtr tmp = std::make_unique<Derived>(Base::INVKEY);
    idx.modify(it, [&tmp](BasePtr& element) { //
        element.swap(tmp);
    });
    idx.erase(it);
    return tmp;
}

int main() {
    ContainerType container;
    fmt::print("Initial: {}\n", container);

    // Insert an element.
    auto& ordered = container.get<Ordered>();
    {
        auto [it, inserted] = ordered.insert(std::make_unique<Derived>(42));
        assert(inserted);
    }
    {
        auto [it, inserted] = ordered.insert(std::make_unique<Derived>(99));
        assert(inserted);
    }
    fmt::print("Inserted: {}\n", container);

    for (size_t key : {42u, 123u, 99u}) {
        BasePtr extracted = extract(ordered, key);
        fmt::print("Extracted for key {}: {}, remain {}\n", key, extracted, container);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Initial: {}
Inserted: {42, 99}
Extracted for key 42: 42, remain {99}
Extracted for key 123: (nullptr), remain {99}
Extracted for key 99: 99, remain {}
```

Comfirm [Compiler Explorer Boost 1.73.0](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/dd8q9b7dP)

Comment: This is nice. I'd prefer a `struct Empty : Base { size_t GetId() const override { return -1; } };` but it's the same principle.

Comment: @TedLyngmo that's indeed even better

Comment: @sehe Thanks for the answer! Just to clarify: one could potentially just default-construct unique_ptr<Base> and do the swap with it inside the modifier lambda. Is the reason your solution uses a concrete Derived due to multi-index container potentially re-sorting the elements after the call to modify?

Comment: The reason is that the key extractor will indirect the unique_ptr - which leads to [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It's also why in my answer I hinted at a second alternative: _"or you can use a key extractor that doesn't require the unique_ptr to be non-null"_

Comment: Just to demonstrate what I meant: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c699d56eaffe2c2b - note that it still requires a special key domain value (INVKEY in my choice) unless your index is non-unique

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Sehe's answer is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57354248/213114). In any case, the recommended course of action is to upgrade Boost and use `extract`.